# Javascript : Find the sum of the metrics for same date but different dimensions in a JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, date

This might appear to be a familiar question. But for my requirement, I wasn't able to land a better and efficient solution. So, please be patient and read through this.

This is my array

```
dataPoints = [{
    "date": "2018-10-01",
    "dim": "Dimension1",
    "metric1": 1,
    "metric2": 1,
    "metric3": 1,
    "metric4": 1
},
{
    "date": "2018-10-01",
    "dim": "Dimension2",
    "metric1": 1,
    "metric2": 1,
    "metric3": 1,
    "metric4": 1
},
{
    "date": "2018-10-01",
    "dim": "Dimension3",
    "metric1": 1,
    "metric2": 1,
    "metric3": 1,
    "metric4": 1
},
{
    "date": "2018-10-02",
    "dim": "Dimension2",
    "metric1": 1,
    "metric2": 1,
    "metric3": 1,
    "metric4": 1
},
{
    "date": "2018-10-02",
    "dim": "Dimension1",
    "metric1": 1,
    "metric2": 1,
    "metric3": 1,
    "metric4": 1
} ];
```

I wanted to find the sum of metric1... metric4 for the given date irrespective of the dimension. In other words, my expected JSON array would look something like below:

```
 result = [{
    "date": "2018-10-01",
    "metric1": 3,
    "metric2": 3,
    "metric3": 3,
    "metric4": 3
},
{
    "date": "2018-10-02",
    "metric1": 2,
    "metric2": 2,
    "metric3": 2,
    "metric4": 2
}  ];
```

I tried something like this :

```
function groupProps(orig, key) {
    var newArr = [],
        groups = {},
        newItem, i, j, cur;
    for (i = 0, j = orig.length; i < j; i++) {
        cur = orig[i];
        if (!(cur[key] in groups)) {
            groups[cur[key]] = {date: cur[key] };
            newArr.push(groups[cur[key]]);
        }        
        for (var prop in cur) {
            if (prop != key) {
                groups[cur[key]][prop] = cur[prop];
            }
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}

console.log(groupProps(dataPoints , "date"))
```

But all I get is :

```
[
  {
        "date": "2018-10-01",
        "dim": "Dimension3",
        "metric1": 1,
        "metric2": 1,
        "metric3": 1,
        "metric4": 1
    },
        "date": "2018-10-02",
        "dim": "Dimension1",
        "metric1": 1,
        "metric2": 1,
        "metric3": 1,
        "metric4": 1
    }

];
```

Can you please provide an efficient workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object for grouping and iterate the wanted entries without `date` and `dim` properties.

```js
const
    dataPoints = [{ date: "2018-10-01", dim: "Dimension1", metric1: 1, metric2: 1, metric3: 1, metric4: 1 }, { date: "2018-10-01", dim: "Dimension2", metric1: 1, metric2: 1, metric3: 1, metric4: 1 }, { date: "2018-10-01", dim: "Dimension3", metric1: 1, metric2: 1, metric3: 1, metric4: 1 }, { date: "2018-10-02", dim: "Dimension2", metric1: 1, metric2: 1, metric3: 1, metric4: 1 }, { date: "2018-10-02", dim: "Dimension1", metric1: 1, metric2: 1, metric3: 1, metric4: 1 }],
    result = Object.values(dataPoints.reduce((r, { date, dim, ...o }) => {
        r[date] ??= { date };
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => r[date][k] = (r[date][k] || 0) + 1);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What does `??` mean?

Comment: it's a [Nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). if that does not work take `if (!r[date]) r[date] = { date };` instead.

Comment: Thanks , why have you given `(r[date][k] || 0) + 1`. ? Shouldn't it be `+v` ?

Comment: that is guarding if `r[date][k]` is not given. in this case zero is taken.